# Why does the Vuex state variable seem to be bound to a component's local variable?

Tags: forms, vue.js, data-binding, vuex

Within my Vue SPA, I am adding and deleting subjects via axios calls.

Within a component, I have an object's (`newCourse`) properties bound to different form elements as seen below. This object is thrown into a function to create a new course. So far so good.

[image: local variables]

[image]

[image]

Above... once the POST resolves, a vuex mutator commits the new course by pushing it to the `allCourses` array. So far so good.

[image]

I run into trouble when I attempt to fill out the form and create another course. When I alter the forms, the old course that was committed seems to be updating/bound to the `newCourse` properties.

If I refresh the page then alter the forms, all is dandy.

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be happening? I'd rather not but I could always `vm.$forceUpdate()`. If anyone needs any additional information, I will attempt to curate.

Thanks so much!

Edit: for more reference: might have something to do with the computed updating somehow?

[image]

As requested, store/actions/mutations below...

[image]

Comment: Post your store and mutations please.

Comment: I don't see your POST request but I'm assuming you're using the same object that you sent to the post as the parameter to the mutator?  In JavaScript and a lot of other programming languages, when you pass an object to a function through a parameter, the object inside of the function references the original object.  This is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thank you @Steven B. for the help! I spent a long time on this and that helped me greatly. Above is where I created a separate object to bring into the commit mutation. This, I would assume, kept the data from being bound to both the component object and the state object.

I'm unsure as to why creating a new object didn't work, but assigning the course object to an empty object did the trick.

Edit: as this question/answer seems to have been about objects in javascript, here is a link explaining the topic in detail.

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Just for future reference, it's common to return the created object from the POST request and then you could use the `response` object which would also solve your issue.